A solution to an equation on trigonometric functions
Consider the equation
$$
2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2} = 0
$$
on $x$ for fixed positive integer $n$.
Is there an explicit solution or an approximate solution for $x$ in each interval $(\frac{2k\pi}{n-1},\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n-1})$, where $k$ is a nonnegative integer.
Yes, previously I ever draw in graph about the function $2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2}$ with small $n$ (see attached figure below). What I can observe are as following:

The graph would be partitioned into seveal parts, say $(\frac{2k \pi}{n-1}, \frac{2(k+1) \pi}{n-1})$ for integer $k$, which can be seen from the unboundness of the $\cot$ funtion at the extreme points of such intervals.

The function $2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2}$ is a periodic function, which is due the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cot$.

We can see exactly exacly one root of $2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2} = 0$ lying on each interval $(\frac{2k\pi}{n-1},\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n-1})$, where $k$ is an integer, except the possible root $x = \pi$ and some other related roots due ot the periodicity.

What I want to work is the explicit or approximate solutions for such roots.


enter image description here
